# I have Google OAuth 2.0 Authorzation Token. When using file_get_contents its saying i'm still not authorized?

Tags: oauth, youtube-api, authorization, token

I've been trying to write a little script with Google's API. I've managed to set it up to get the actual access token and echo it in the browser but when i try to:

```
$views = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&start-date=2014-09-29&end-date=2014-10-29&metrics=views&key={key}');
var_dump($views);
```

It's still giving me the default error of

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

If any more information is needed like my request, please let me know. I feel that maybe i'll be missing something simple like usual :l !!!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Parameter for the access token is `access_token`, not `key`.

Your URL has to be

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&start-date=2014-09-29&end-date=2014-10-29&metrics=views&access_token={access_token}
```